# Check if the element is above or below in the DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I have the following DOM structure of interest:

```
<div id="portfolioItems">

    <div class="portfolioItemsLine">
        <div class="portfolioItem selected">1</div>
        <div class="portfolioItem">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolioItemsLine">
        <div class="portfolioItem">3</div>
        <div class="portfolioItem">4</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Each .porfolioItem has a click handler attached. From within the click handler function, I need to determine, whether the $('.portfolioItem.selected') is located above the currently clicked portfolioItem, or below it.

The problem in determining is introduced by the fact that each two portfolioItems are "packed" into the item line divs.

How can I check the above/below positioning in respect to .selected item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.portfolioItem').click(
    function(){
        var selectedAt = $('.portfolioItem.selected').index('.portfolioItem'),
            curIndex = $(this).index('.portfolioItem');
        if (curIndex > selectedAt){
            // the clicked item is 'later' than the .selected item in the DOM
            console.log('"later"');
        }
        else if (curIndex < selectedAt){
            // the clicked item is 'earlier' than the .selected item in the DOM
            console.log('"earlier"');
        }
        else if (curIndex == selectedAt){
            // the clicked item is the .selected item
            console.log('"equal"');
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nAyr8/).

References:

- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `index()` function, it finds an element in a collection. If selected properly, the elements of the collection are a "flat" list (you don't have to worry about the "div/line" classes) :)

```
$(".portfolioItem").click(
    function()
    {
        var items = $("#portfolioItems .portfolioItem");
        var selected = $("#portfolioItems .selected");
        var i = $(items).index(selected);
        var j = $(items).index(this);
        console.log(i,j);
        // compare i and j to understand if above or below
    }
);​
```